# DPDK library packet function query

Tags: dpdk

What is the use case of below functions? kindly give detailed information.
I have allocated the Mbuf and when i have to use below functions

```
1.rte_pktmbuf_prepend()
2.rte_pktmbuf_append()
3.rte_pktmbuf_adj()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions help to mark up mbufs for data manipulations. They care to update mbuf fields `data_off`, `data_len` and `pkt_len`, so that the caller may not worry about that.

When creating an mbuf pool, the user must request that per-mbuf data room be at least `RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM` bytes long (typically, 128 bytes). And when a new mbuf is allocated from the pool, its default starting position for data (`data_off`) is set to that `RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM`. If some entity (in example, a NIC's PMD) writes packet data to an mbuf, then its `data_off` will still be greater than or equal to `RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM`. This way, DPDK makes sure to preserve some unused space at the beginning of each mbuf's data buffer so that applications may use it to attach extra (outer) headers to packets they handle.

With above explanation in mind, `rte_pktmbuf_prepend` is a helper which makes extra room *before* the existing data start and returns a pointer to the newly claimed space. The application can then copy extra data to that location. For example, when an application receives non-tunnel packets and wants to encapsulate them using a VXLAN header, it may invoke this function to make some space, then fill in the header itself. Another example is VLAN tag insertion. See [more examples](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/search?q=rte_pktmbuf_prepend).

As opposed to `rte_pktmbuf_prepend`, helper `rte_pktmbuf_adj` is used to dismiss some amount of data at the beginning of an mbuf. For example, when an application receives encapsulated (tunnel) packets, it may want to drop the outer header by invoking this function. The resulting packets will have their data start positions pointing at the *inner* headers. See [more examples](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/search?q=rte_pktmbuf_adj).

As for `rte_pktmbuf_append`, it finds the last mbuf segment of a packet mbuf and reserves data room *after* the existing data. For example, it may be used to construct a packet brick by brick: first append an Ethernet header, then append an IP header, etc. Alternatively, one may invoke this method just once to make room for the whole packet right from the start. See [more examples](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/search?q=rte_pktmbuf_append).